# shlex preserving double quotes?

Tags: python, shlex

I'm using `Popen` with `shlex` for a yum command with the `--exclude` flag to pass a list of packages to be excluded. For some reason it seems `shlex` is not preserving the double quotes. Any pointers how do i go about this ?

```
>>> import shlex
>>> x = '/usr/bin/yum update --exclude=\"foo bar baz*\"'   
>>> print shlex.split(x)
['/usr/bin/yum', 'update', '--exclude=foo bar baz*']
```

With the POSIX mode off, the quotes seem misplaced.

```
>>> print shlex.split(x,posix=False)
['/usr/bin/yum', 'update', '--exclude="foo', 'bar', 'baz*"']
```

Comment: This seems to work when it comes to preserving the string inside the double quotes. Any pointers how do i split this command further,excluding whats inside --exclude ?

    x = r'/usr/bin/yum update --exclude="foo bar baz*"'
    >>> print re.split(' (?=\[)', x)
    ['/usr/bin/yum update --exclude="foo bar baz*"']

Answer (score 4):

First, your parameters will already arrive correct in the target program's argv/argc via normal `shlex.split(x)` - as shown here :

```
>>> x = '/usr/bin/yum update --exclude=\"foo bar baz*\"' 
>>> l = shlex.split(x); l
['/usr/bin/yum', 'update', '--exclude=foo bar baz*']
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', "import sys;print(sys.argv)"] + l, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdout.read()
"['-c', '/usr/bin/yum', 'update', '--exclude=foo bar baz*']\r\n"
```

: The quotes on the shell are there for keeping the parameter string together for correct splitting in the target app; and with split arguments, the split is already done.

---

Second, you can use `shell=True` on Popen and you can pass the command string unsplit:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(x, shell=True, ...)
```

: This way the string `x` is directly interpreted by the shell  - e.g. bash. But an extra shell process is involved and consumes resources and run time

---

Third, if you really want to get the quotes your way into the target program via shlex.split and direct program call, and **when** you have control over the input string, then you can the write the input string like this (Extra quoting the same as in shell(-mode)):

```
>>> x = '/usr/bin/yum update --exclude="\\"foo bar baz*\\""' 
>>> l = shlex.split(x); l
['/usr/bin/yum', 'update', '--exclude="foo bar baz*"']
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', "import sys;print(sys.argv)"] + l, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print(p.stdout.read())
['-c', '/usr/bin/yum', 'update', '--exclude="foo bar baz*"']
```

(note: one backslash in the input string is consume by python syntax unless your write it in r-syntax: `x = r'/usr/bin/yum update --exclude="\"foo bar baz*\\""'`

---

Fourth, if you want get your **given** input string with the quotes into the target programm, then you need to employ a custom shell syntax - e.g. via a REGEX:

```
>>> x = '/usr/bin/yum update --exclude=\"foo bar baz*\"' 
>>> l = re.findall(r'(?:[^\s,"]|"(?:\\.|[^"])*")+', x); l
['/usr/bin/yum', 'update', '--exclude="foo bar baz*"']
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-c', "import sys;print(sys.argv)"] + l, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> print(p.stdout.read())
['-c', '/usr/bin/yum', 'update', '--exclude="foo bar baz*"']
```